# Which language is used to write a C compiler?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction

PHP's interpreter is written in C. In which language is a C compiler written? Assembly language?

Comment: There are a lot of different implementations of C compilers out there. Do you have any specific compiler in mind?

Comment: I think the C compiler is written in a mixture of C and assembler, but mainly C/

Comment: See this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657454/is-gcc-c-compiler-written-in-c-itself][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657454/is-gcc-c-compiler-written-in-c-itself

Comment: C is not interpreted language. It directly translates into assembly. So it is not written in anything. Compilers and linkers are written, usually, in C or C++. Assembly, on the other hand, is CPU (architecture) specific and is implemented in hardware using, for example, HDL (like Verilog, VHDL etc).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2464847/17034

Comment: A brand new language will likely be written in some other common/popular language, then at some point the compiler re-written in that language so that it can self host.  Currently C compilers are written in C because it is not a new language.  Other languages may never be written in their own language if the language is not one that can be used for that task.

Comment: @dwelch: or it might never happen if it could be done but is pointless. For example, `javac` is written in Java (it's a compiler that compiles Java source to Java bytecode), but Hotspot (which is also in part a compiler, specifically it compiles Java bytecode to native instructions) isn't. You *could* write the compiler part of a JIT in Java (if not necessarily the part that interacts with the runtime to actually patch the code together), but you probably wouldn't want to.

Comment: There are C compilers written in Coq (which is not a Turing-complete language at all). Practically, you can write a C compiler in any decent language.

Answer (score 1):

the C-Compiler is written in C with the use of a minimal bootstrap compiler in another language

Comment: And the minimal bootstrap compiler was written about 40 years ago, and no longer exists :-)

Comment: **the** C-compiler? Which one?

Comment: @bitmask: is there another one :-)

Comment: I bootstrap new C compilers from my not-so-minimal C compiler (well, I guess some might consider GCC or clang minimal).

Comment: @OP: it is in most cases a good proof of concept to write a compiler/interpreter for a new language with the help of this new language. It shows, that the new language is at least able to express itself

Comment: @sfstewman: you are right. I would adjust my answer, but it is not worth it, because the question is closed already